# SQL - Get only rows that contains only 'A' character

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I use MySQL 5.6 .
I have a table Person with a column parents which contains a string of A and B letters.

For example :

- person 1 parents column look like AAAABAABBAAABAABA
- person 2 parents column look like AAAAAAAAAA
- person 3 parents column look like BBBBBBBBBBBBB
- person 4 parents column look like BABBAAB

I would like to get persons where parents string contains only A letter.
I already managed to do this by :

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE parents NOT LIKE '%B%'
```

This worked but it is terrible in performance. I tried to add an index but its not better because of starting % I think.

Maybe it is quite simple but I can't find the solution to my problem.

Comment: Are the strings different lengths?

Comment: I'd try `WHERE parents <= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA'`. (Where  'AAAAAAAAAAAAA' has maximum length, for the parents column.)

Comment: @jarlh I forgot to say that all rows doesn't have the same number of characters. So it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the LOCATE function?

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s06.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM parents 
WHERE REPLACE(parents , 'A', '') = ''
```

Comment: Subquery is really not needed; you can move the `VAL` expression to `WHERE` clause. Also, it would be better to use `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead of `LENGTH()`

Comment: @ybert move the condition to `WHERE` clause. `SELECT * FROM route_shape WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(point_type_encoded, 'A', '')) = 0`

Comment: Performance still terrible. (I have 10 millions rows in my Person table)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to speed the query, then you want it to use an index.  Functions on the column are not appropriate, because they generally prevent indexes from being used.  So, you might be stuck with `in`:

```
where parents in ('A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AAAA', . . . .)
```

Be sure you have an index on `parents`.

I think you can also phrase this as:

```
where parents in (repeat('A', 1), repeat('A', 2), . . . )
```

However, I'm not 100% sure if MySQL will use an index in this case (but it is worth testing).

Comment: It is not possible as I can have like 2000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to MYSQL but try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE soundex(parents) = soundex('A')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM parents 
WHERE parents <= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA'
```

(Where the `'AAAAAAAAAAAAA'` literal has the maximum length, for the parents column.)

Comment: I forgot to say that all rows doesn't have the same number of characters. So it will not work.

Comment: At least you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will struggle to find any performant solution to this problem. My suggestion would be to add a new column which indicates that the value is comprised only of the letter 'A' (using a trigger to set it on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`), and use that in your `WHERE` clause instead:

```
ALTER TABLE Person ADD COLUMN alla TINYINT DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TRIGGER checkA BEFORE INSERT ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.alla = REPLACE(NEW.parents, 'A', '') = '';

CREATE TRIGGER checkAupd BEFORE UPDATE ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.alla = REPLACE(NEW.parents, 'A', '') = '';
```

Then you can simply

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE alla = 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nJFrHGLPHRUh1Cq7EbeQDS/2)

You could of course do the same thing for 'B', which would then allow you to determine if a column was either all 'A' (`alla = 1`) or all 'B' (`allb = 1`) or neither (`alla = 0 AND allb = 0`).